# DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found. When trying to use psutil

Tags: python, python-3.x, dll, windows-10, psutil

I am trying to use psutil in python.
I installed it with pip but when i run my program i get this error :

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\axel\Documents\GoRaise\class\main.py", line 16, in <module>
>     import psutil, time, subprocess   File "C:\Users\axel\Documents\GoRaise\venv\lib\site-packages\psutil\__init__.py",
> line 109, in <module>
>     from . import _pswindows as _psplatform   File "C:\Users\axel\Documents\GoRaise\venv\lib\site-packages\psutil\_pswindows.py",
> line 35, in <module>
>     from ._psutil_windows import ABOVE_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS ImportError: DLL load failed: La procédure spécifiée est introuvable
```

I have seen on other posts that I should use something like Dependency Walker to open the .pyd file and see what .dll is missing.

Dependency Walker couldn't work on my computer, it was crashing (I think I saw someone said that it was because of win10), so I used [this](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) instead.

I opened `_psutil_windows.pyd` with this and the only thing i saw was the python3.dll that seemed to be wrong. So i downloaded it [there](https://www.dll4free.com/python3.dll.html) and replaced it in the given folder.

The problem is that it still not working. I still go the same error when i run my program and I'm out of ideas to fix that.

Any idea?

EDIT :

Here's the result of what CristiFati asked :

```
> 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] C:\Users\axelp\Documents\GoRaise\venv\Scripts\python.exe
> ['C:\\Users\\axelp\\Documents\\GoRaise\\class',
> 'C:\\Users\\axelp\\Documents\\GoRaise',
> 'C:\\Users\\axelp\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start
> Menu\\Programs\\Python 3.7',
> 'C:\\Users\\axelp\\Documents\\GoRaise\\venv\\Scripts\\python36.zip',
> 'C:\\Users\\axelp\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\DLLs',
> 'C:\\Users\\axelp\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib',
> 'C:\\Users\\axelp\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36',
> 'C:\\Users\\axelp\\Documents\\GoRaise\\venv',
> 'C:\\Users\\axelp\\Documents\\GoRaise\\venv\\lib\\site-packages']
> C:\Users\axelp\Documents\GoRaise
```

Comment: `print(sys.version, sys.executable, sys.path, os.getcwd())` before `import psutil` and paste the results in the question. Remove the file *python3.dll* that you copied (and try avoiding that practice). How did you install *PSUtil*?

Comment: @CristiFati It's done. I installed PSUtil by going into the terminal of my venv and runing "pip install psutil"

Comment: Could not reproduce . Hey, what's with that entry: *'C:\\Users\\axelp\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Python 3.7'* ?